# Using an hypothesis to remove cases in a match statement

Tags: coq

I would like to *use an hypothesis in a function to rule out some of the cases in a `match` statement.*  I wonder how this is done in Coq.

A very simple example is a function that uses `match` on a `nat`.  I would like to use an hypothesis that says that `n <> 0` so that I won't have to provide a match pattern for `0`, like this:

```
Fixpoint minus_1 (n:nat) (H:n<>0): nat :=
  match n with
    | S n' => n'
  end.
```

The above example gives `Error: Non exhaustive pattern-matching: no clause found for pattern 0`.

How do I make use of `H` to not have to provide a pattern for `0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rely on the Program library to fill some gaps for you, for example:

```
Require Import Arith Program.

Program Fixpoint minus_1 (n: nat) (h: n <> 0) : nat :=
  match n with
    | S p => p
    | _ => _
  end.
```

or you can build the term "by hand" using tactics (in v8.4):

```
Fixpoint minus_1 (n: nat) (h: n <> 0) {struct n} : nat.
destruct n as [ | p ].
- case h; reflexivity.
- exact p.
Defined.
```

Here is a version that should work on older version of Coq:

```
Definition minus_1 (n: nat) (h: n <> 0) : nat.
revert h.
elim n.
intros heq; case heq; reflexivity.
intros p _ _; exact p.
Defined.
```

In all cases, you can use `Print minus_1.` to see the resulting term.

Comment: Thanks!  The last two examples was what I was looking for.  (The first one is not so safe if one has a more complex example and one actually may forget some important case.)

Comment: Note that your function is not a real fixpoint, you should defined it using ``Definition``. In case of real recursive call, you have to use the tactic ``fix``, and be sure to use it on a subterm to be able to pass the termination checker.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `return` annotation on the match:

```
Lemma notNotEqual : forall x:nat, (x <> x) -> False.
auto.
Qed.

Definition predecessor (n:nat) : n<>0 -> nat :=
  match n return (n <> 0 -> nat) with
    | 0 =>
      fun H : 0 <> 0 => 
        match notNotEqual 0 H with end
    | S m => fun _ => m
  end.
```

This is covered in Adam Chlipala's book, ["Certified Programming with Dependent Types"](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/), starting in [the chapter on Inductive Types](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/InductiveTypes.html). It is also covered in [Chapter 17 of the Coq manual, "Extended pattern-matching"](http://coq.inria.fr/coq/refman/Reference-Manual020.html), by Cristina Cornes and Hugo Herbelin.

You could also mix the function style with the tactics style using `refine`:

```
Definition predecessor_alt (n:nat) : n<>0 -> nat.
refine 
  (match n return (n <> 0 -> nat) with
     | 0 => _
     | S m => fun _ => m
   end).
intros; assert False as nope.
auto.
inversion nope.
Defined.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Being able to use the match statement makes the function a bit more readable.  I'm still struggling with understanding when a return is needed or not...